# Can't start my import statements with the top-level module (the source folder)

Tags: python, path, pydev, python-import

I seem to be running into this issue intermittently.

Sometimes I have a PyDev project in which I get compile errors if I try to start my imports with the name of the top-level folder. So, suppose my project looks like this:

```
+ myproject
    - __init__.py
    - a.py
    - b.py
    + package1
        - c.py
        - __init__.py
    + package2
        - d.py
        - e.py
        - __init__.py
```

If I'm in file a.py, it won't let me do imports like this, for example:

```
from myproject.b import foo
import myproject.b
```

The same goes for any file. They all compile just fine if I leave off "myproject" from the imports statement like this:

```
from b import foo
import b
```

Just like in the diagram, I definitely have a top-level __init__.py, and both the myproject folder and its parent are on the Python path. The myproject folder is also the source folder for the project.

I need the complete import statement because places I'm deploying this code to won't have the myproject folder on their path. Some other projects that seem to be configured the same way don't have this problem, and I've tried the usual cleaning/restarting.

Any idea as to what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: If places you deply the code to don't have the myproject folder on their path, `import myproject.b` will fail.

Comment: Are you really getting a compile error? Python doesn't care whether modules you're referencing do or don't exist at compile time, and it doesn't even compile your code until you're running it. If it's an `ImportError`, that's not a compile error.

Comment: Yeah, I mispoke. It's an `ImportError`.

Comment: BrenBam, uh, I don't think that's correct. They just need whatever folder myproject resides in to be on the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried relative imports (`from .b import foo`, `from . import b`)?  I don't understand why absolute imports (including "myproject") doesn't work in your case but meanwhile relative imports should still work.

Comment: No relative imports allowed.

Comment: Why?  They've been around since 2.5 and PEP8 deems them acceptable too.

Comment: People at my office don't like them.

Answer (score 1):

So, after tinkering a bit, it turns out that PyDev won't let me start an import statement with a package that itself is on the Python path. If I remove the source folder designation from my project folder, the imports work fine, but then of course I lose some of PyDev's functionality.

So, my new problem is slightly different, so I've posted a different question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613944/how-should-i-structure-my-pydev-git-project